# Safest way to get $_SESSION variable in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a scenario where I need an ID (from a PHP variable) in JavaScript. Which would be the best way of adding the value to the page?

```
<input type="hidden" name="variable" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
```

or

```
var $variable = <?php echo $value; ?>;
```

Thanks for any feedback or advice.

Comment: I would say the first method... More importantly though, you should use what ever method is more consistent with the existing code.

Comment: there's no safest way. it's an architectural design subject. the safest way is to avoid injection. for the JS variant, use `echo json_encode($value)` instead of `echo $value`.

Comment: ... and use `htmlspecialchars($value)` for the HTML variant.